# Complex Analysis ( Open/Closed Set).

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

let $z = re^{i\theta}$ ,

How do we prove that , $0\leq \operatorname{arg}(z)\leq\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ ($z \neq 0$), is neither a open set nor a closed set.

$\operatorname{arg}(z)$ is nothing but $\theta$ here and hence, $0\leq \theta\leq\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, it seems to be a closed set (as it includes the boundary values) , so how to prove that it is not open/closed set?
HELP!

Comment: What about $z = 0$?

Answer (score 2):

Every neighbourhood of $0$ contains an open disk centered $D$ at $0$, and $D$ has points inside and outside the set, but $0$ is not in the set.

Answer (score 2):

$z=1$ is a point of the set but no open neighbourhood of $z=1$ belongs to the set, so it is not open. Every element of the sequence $z_n=\frac{1+i}{n}$ belongs to the set, but the limit point $z=0$ does not, so the set is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Point 1+i is in the set, however disc centered at 1+i with radius €/2 contain point 1+i+€/2 but this point is not in the set, hence is not open. similarly, you can prove that the set is not close. The point i is in complement of the set, but i-€/2 for any given €>0 contain 0 which is not in this set. The set is neither open nor closed